# Objective-C Post JSON to WebApi Controller

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, json, asp.net-web-api, nsurlconnection

I have the following javascript function which posts data back to a ASP.NET Web Api controller:

```
var d = {
    NorthEastPoint: {
        Latitude: boundingBox.ne.lat,
        Londitude: boundingBox.ne.lng
    },
    SouthWestPoint: {
        Latitude: boundingBox.sw.lat,
        Londitude: boundingBox.sw.lng
    },
    CurrentLocation: {
        Latitude: 0,
        Londitude: 0
    },
    IncludeFullImage: false
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(d));

var endPoint = 'http://127.0.0.1/api/Search/';

$.ajax({
    url: endPoint,
    type: 'POST',
    data: d,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function (content) {
            return 'cannot find resource';
        },
        505: function (content) {
            return 'internal server error';
        }
    },
    error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
        // handle status === "timeout"
        // handle other errors

    }
});
```

This post works fine. I am attempting to replicate the ajax post within Objective-C using NSURLConnection.

Here is my Objective-C code where I create the json:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

NSDictionary *NorthEastPoint = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:_pointOneLat],@"Latitude",
                                [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:_pointOneLon],@"Londitude",nil];

NSDictionary *SouthWestPoint = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:_pointTwoLat],@"Latitude",
                                [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:_pointTwoLon],@"Londitude",nil];
NSDictionary *CurrentLocation = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:_currentLat],@"Latitude",
                                [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:_currentLon],@"Londitude",nil];

[dict setObject:NorthEastPoint forKey:@"NorthEastPoint"];
[dict setObject:SouthWestPoint forKey:@"SouthWestPoint"];
[dict setObject:CurrentLocation forKey:@"CurrentLocation"];
[dict setObject:@"false" forKey:@"IncludeFullImage"];


NSError *writeError = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);
```

The output of the above is:

```
JSON Output: {
  "NorthEastPoint" : {
    "Londitude" : 1.388894,
    "Latitude" : 57.49198
  },
  "CurrentLocation" : {
    "Londitude" : -6.12792,
    "Latitude" : 53.24554
  },
  "SouthWestPoint" : {
    "Londitude" : -5.642355,
    "Latitude" : 52.30821
  },
  "IncludeFullImage" : "false"
}
```

I then try to post the json to my WebApi Controller using the following code:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.20.10.5/apisite/api/Search"];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        [self.delegate searchDidStart];
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    } else {

    }
```

Upon posting the the controller, I can see my post is successful as a break point is hit, however the model data is not populated.
My controller method is looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PlaceDTO>> Post(BoxSearchParam model) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

and BoxSearchParam is defined as:

```
public class BoxSearchParam
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BoxSearchParam"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public BoxSearchParam()
        {
            this.NorthEastPoint = new MapPoint();
            SouthWestPoint = new MapPoint();
            CurrentLocation = new MapPoint();
            MaximumSearchRadius = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxDistanceBetweenPoints"]);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the north west point.
        /// </summary>
        public MapPoint NorthEastPoint { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the south east point.
        /// </summary>
        public MapPoint SouthWestPoint { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current location.
        /// </summary>
        public MapPoint CurrentLocation { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the maximum search radius.
        /// </summary>
        public int MaximumSearchRadius { get; internal set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether include full image.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IncludeFullImage { get; set; }
    }
```

MapPoint is defined as:

```
public class MapPoint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MapPoint"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MapPoint()
        {
            Londitude = 0;
            Latitude = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the londitude.
        /// </summary>
        public decimal Londitude { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the latitude.
        /// </summary>
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong with the posting of data, from what I can see I have replicated the functionality in the javascript post, so I am at a loss as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Try charles proxy on your mac to see what actually goes over the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line `[dict setObject:@"false" forKey:@"IncludeFullImage"];`

to
  [dict [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"IncludeFullImage"];

and try again. Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to mark your answer as correct as it set me on the right path. What I needed was: [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"IncludeFullImage"];

Comment: However, I was still experiencing the same behaviour even with that, what finally solved it was adding request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"] to the actual request.